# Convert wide format data to long format using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-manipulation

I recently started working with SQL for data manipulation. So, forgive me if this is too basic.
I have data table1 in the following format.

```
id  pg_a  pg_b
12   1     0
35   1     1
46   0     1
```

And I would like to convert this into a long format like shown in the following table.

```
id  pg  value
12  a     1
12  b     0
35  a     1
35  b     1
46  a     0
46  a     1
```

I have an sql query using case when but, in no luck. The query only executes the first when in both case statements.

This is the query:

```
select id,
(case when pg_a is not null then pg_a
     when pg_b is not null then pg_b
     else null 
 end) AS pg,
(case when pg_a is not null then a
      when pg_b is not null then b
      else null
 end) AS value
from table1
```

What do I need to do differently?  Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.id, v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('a', pg_a), ('b', pg_b)
     ) v(pg, value);
```

If you are new to SQL, you might you might be more comfortable with `union all`:

```
select id, 'a' as pg, pg_a as value
from t
union all
select id, 'b', pg_b
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The query with union worked. As for lateral join, I dont understand what v.* does. I am looking it up though. Performance wise, is lateral join more efficient as compared to using union? Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: Since Gordon's answer solved your problem you should accept it. This helps future questioners whit the same issue. Please do not leave open a successfully answered question.

Comment: @savi . . . `v.*` selects all the columns in `v`.  And yes a lateral join is faster than `union all` because it scans the table only once.  This has little impact unless the table is large or is really a complex query (say a view or CTE).